# Lotus Notes Electronic Ink Signature

Tags: .net, lotus-notes, electronic-signature

I am looking into how to have a user with a touchscreen computer or tablet sign their name using the touch screen on the main Lotus Notes client. I found an XPages solution, but that only works for the web, and not the downloaded lotus notes.

All and any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Notes 8.5 or later Xpages can be run natively in the Notes client.

You can open your Xpages using an url like this notes://server/db/myxpage.xsp?openxpage

Comment: I am only using Notes 8